# C# Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'float'

Tags: c#

I'm smoothing a Vector 3 angle, but right now I take in my smooth a vector 3 angle. Right now the smoothing factor is 0-1 with 1 being no smooth. But I would like to have the smoothing factor 0-100 with 100 being no smooth. So I came up with this hoping it would work.

```
        public static Vector3 SmoothAngle(this Vector3 src, Vector3 dest, float smoothAmount)
    {
        Vector3 SmoothedAngle;
        SmoothedAngle = dest - src;
        SmoothedAngle = ClampAngle(SmoothedAngle);
        SmoothedAngle = src + SmoothedAngle / 100f * (100f - smoothAmount);
        Console.WriteLine(SmoothedAngle);
        return ClampAngle(SmoothedAngle);
    }
```

But I get the error as stated in my title.
This is my vector 3 class.

```
public struct Vector3
{
    #region VARIABLES
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
    #endregion

    #region PROPERTIES
    public static Vector3 Zero => new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    public static Vector3 UnitX => new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    public static Vector3 UnitY => new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    public static Vector3 UnitZ => new Vector3(0, 0, 1);

    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTOR
    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
    public Vector3(Vector3 vec) : this(vec.X, vec.Y, vec.Z) { }
    public Vector3(float[] values) : this(values[0], values[1], values[2]) { }
    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    public float Length()
    {
        return (float)Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2) + Math.Pow(Z, 2)));
    }
    public float DistanceTo(Vector3 other)
    {
        return (this - other).Length();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Vector3 vec = (Vector3)obj;
        return GetHashCode() == vec.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode() ^ Z.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[X={X.ToString()}, Y={Y.ToString()}, Z={Z.ToString()}]";
    }
    #endregion

    #region OPERATORS
    public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return new Vector3(v1.X + v2.X, v1.Y + v2.Y, v1.Z + v2.Z);
    }
    public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return new Vector3(v1.X - v2.X, v1.Y - v2.Y, v1.Z - v2.Z);
    }
    public static Vector3 operator *(Vector3 v1, float scalar)
    {
        return new Vector3(v1.X * scalar, v1.Y * scalar, v1.Z * scalar);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return v1.X == v2.X && v1.Y == v2.Y && v1.Z == v2.Z;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return !(v1 == v2);
    }
    public float this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    return X;
                case 1:
                    return Y;
                case 2:
                    return Z;
                default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    X = value;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Y = value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Z = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I see you overridden the operator `*` to work with scalars, but I don't see the operator `/`.

Comment: But you haven't overloaded `operator /`, have you? I guess you could use `SmoothedAngle * (1f / 100f)` instead of `SmoothedAngle / 100f`, or something if for some reason you don't want to write that overload...

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault You are right. It's to late to code must have missed it. THanks.

Comment: Your Equals operator is incorrect and overloading == for mutable objects is not recommended see msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've implemented the `*` operator, but not the `/` operator.

```
public static Vector3 operator /(Vector3 v1, float scalar)
{
    return new Vector3(v1.X / scalar, v1.Y / scalar, v1.Z / scalar);
}
```